# Which Gold Badges Can Be Awarded Multiple Times?

Tags: discussion, badges

Are there any gold badges that can be awarded multiple times? If so, which ones?

I have seen that the moderation badges can only be awarded once per type, so those are out. How about the Fanatic badge? If for example, you visit 200 days in a row, would you get two gold badges for it?

Does anyone have a definitive list?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for

Comment: @DavyM Ahh, that's kinda surprising, for some reason I assumed the Fanatic badge would be one that would get awarded multiple times.

Comment: Related: *[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397)* (I don't know why they changed the title)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1188000) should list all 11 (okay 12) possible Gold badges (not tag based) that are awarded more then once to a user.

Except that it lists 12 of them:

- Famous Question
- Great Answer
- Great Question
- Lifeboat
- Populist
- Publicist
- Reversal
- Sheriff  (WUT?!?, in theory this is possible)
- Socratic
- Stellar Question
- Steward
- Unsung Hero

Who has *Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year.* **twice** ... it turns out that [Alex Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff?userid=651805) managed to do that. I guess because he has access to the production database. Which proves once more that you really need to keep your security tight ...

Comment: Alex's case aside, it is not unexpected that someone could meet the requirements for the Sheriff badge twice. You get elected as moderator, serve for at least one year, then step down. Subsequently, you apply for reinstatement, are reinstated, and serve again for at least one year.

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough. And with the new reinstatement process that has become much more likely ...

Comment: Arguably less likely. There didn't used to be a reinstatement "process" beyond pestering Shog9 to push the right button to grant you access again. :-) Well, except for pro-tem mods of beta sites, who previously weren't eligible for reinstatement all, unless they won an election. With the new process, they now are.

Comment: Thanks @rene. Awesome answer. Just curious, how did you get all of your gold's? Are those from tags?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein It's worth noting that, although Meta and main have the same reputation, they *do* have different badges. You can see the badges that rene has earned on Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=badges); most of them are from high-quality answers, especially to unpopular questions/proposals. You can see his badges on the main site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=badges).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @CodyGray

Comment: I wonder how you would get the unsung hero badge more than once. Is this when you qualify, then due to acceptance/answer rates no longer qualify, and then re-qualify later on? That doesn't seem right because someone just sitting on the tipping point for a long time will get loads of them...

Comment: @Plutian probably another glitch.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe slightly tongue in cheek, but all tag badges can be awarded multiple times (even if you cannot have more than 1 of each one at a time)

- get upvoted to 1000 points in the tag => get the tag badge
- get downvoted below 1000 points => lose the tag badge
- repeat